# How were the "richest and best endowed universities" funded in the 1700s?

Tags: education

Adam Smith ([1776](https://www.marxists.org/reference/archive/smith-adam/works/wealth-of-nations/book05/ch01c-2.htm)):

> In some of the richest and best endowed universities, the tutors content themselves with teaching a few unconnected shreds and parcels of this corrupted course; and even these they commonly teach very negligently and superficially. The improvements which, in modern times, have been made in several different branches of philosophy have not, the greater part of them, been made in universities, though some no doubt have. The greater part of universities have not even been very forward to adopt those improvements after they were made; and several of those learned societies have chosen to remain, for a long time, the sanctuaries in which exploded systems and obsolete prejudices found shelter and protection after they had been hunted out of every other corner of the world. In general, the richest and best endowed universities have been the slowest in adopting those improvements, and the most averse to permit any considerable change in the established plan of education. Those improvements were more easily introduced into some of the poorer universities, in which the teachers, depending upon their reputation for the greater part of their subsistence, were obliged to pay more attention to the current opinions of the world.

[Edward Gibbon](https://books.google.com/books?id=6IcaAAAAYAAJ&pg=RA3-PA27&dq=%22Incredible%20as%20the%20fact%20may%20appear,%20I%20must%20rest%20my%20belief%20on%20the%20positive%22):

> Incredible as the fact may appear, I must rest my belief on the positive and impartial evidence of a master of moral and political wisdom, who had himself resided at Oxford. Dr. Adam Smith assigns as the cause of their indolence, that, instead of being paid by voluntary contributions, which would urge them to increase the number, and to deserve the gratitude of their pupils, the Oxford professors are secure in the enjoyment of a fixed stipend, without the necessity of labour, or the apprehension of controul.

How were the "richest and best endowed universities" funded? Who was paying for the professors' fixed stipends?

Comment: The hint is in the word *endowed*

Comment: Monarchs, governments, wealthy aristocrats, the church and student fees.